# Snowflake SQL REGEXP - Capturing After Hyphen Before File Extension

Tags: sql, regex

Looking to capture a customer code that appears after a hyphen and before the .file_extension ...
Example: `DWL-202_EJJFT_Transactions-EOTTFFS001.csv`
In this case, I want to capture `EOTTFFS001` as my account code.

Thus far I have tried working with `RIGHT` but since our customers have different length codes, sometimes I end up with `-DJTSM001.csv` because, in this case, the customer had a five-letter code. This approach also does not remove CSV. I have also tried to nest a `RIGHT` statement inside of another `RIGHT` statement but that does not seem to work.

My goal is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Comment: Please show your urrent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the non-hyphenated string just before the last period:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '-([^-]+)[.][^.-]+$', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Comment: Gordon congrats on over 1M rep. That's huge. I saw a thread about you earlier! Lol

Seems to almost solve the problem. Still need to remove the ".csv" at the end, and this one keeps the "-" in the beginning. That can be corrected for with a RIGHT and LEFT statement most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a `split_part` based alternative in there

```
select split_part(replace(col,'-','.'),'.',-2) -- -2 gets you the second last item
```